# How to achieve following shown effect in android textview

Tags: android, textview

I want To create UI as shown below in android.
[image]

In above we can see textview over imageview i did it using framelayout.
But my question is how do i achieve textview as shown below i.e if textview 
text is exceeding then ... is shown.How to achieve this effect in textview.

My xml code is shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_img"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/nature1"/> 
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding these lines to your `TextView` :

```
android:maxLines="2" 
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: I tried but its not working i am not getting ..... after trucation of text.
Thanks For Your Reply.

Comment: You'll get the `...` only if the text is larger than the `TextView`